# How to make Hair without use of particles system?

Tags: hair

I'm searching for technique to make realistic hairs in blender internal without using particle system.

I found this trick
[image]

[image]
But is there any way to do this in blender?

Any answer will be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This technique is called poly-hair.

There are a couple of different approaches but these are the basic steps:

1) **Render/download a hair patch**

Create and render out a hair patch created with the particle system.
Bake a normal map for extra detail in your render as well.

Make a couple of them so you get some variation.

2) **The patches**

Model a couple of hair patches and UV un-wrap them to match your rendered hair patches.

3) **Placement**

This step will take the most time if you want a realistic result.
Place and edit each strand individually. Layer them on top of each other, make them blend well, ...

This image might help this explanation.
[image]

Look on youtube and google for more detailed steps and info on the shading.