# How to use images for hair in Blender Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, image, hair

I have a model in Blender Cycles and for its hair I use a diffuse image and a normal image (hair_d, hair_n).

How do i use them in my model? I don't know how use nodes, I tried but the result was wrong. My models hair will get blue, or just black.

How do I need to use these images? Please just show me an example of how to connect the nodes together. My Blender Cycles version: 2.79

Thanks

Comment: [Edit] your question and show some screenshots of the model and hair images you want to use for the hair. Maybe related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92790/how-to-make-hair-without-use-of-particles-system

Comment: Maybe post the textures you got. Also post the .blend file or at least a screenshot of you material-setup and the hair mesh (in edit mode).

Comment: check this outstanding tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KpVyTc_72z0

Comment: This Question might already have answer : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/92790/how-to-make-hair-without-use-of-particles-system